# SUM function sometimes takes more than 30 seconds

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I'm using POSTGRESQL database and have pretty simple query that calculates total revenue for selected time period (**startDate** and **endDate** input parameters).

Here is **public.processedorder** table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.processedorder (
    "OrderId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "ChannelId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "ShippingId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "CountryId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "LocationId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "PackagingId" int4 NOT NULL,
    "ConvertedTotal" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "ConvertedSubtotal" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "ConvertedShippingCost" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "ConvertedShippingTax" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "ConvertedTax" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "ConvertedDiscount" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "ConversionRate" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "Currency" varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    "OriginalTotal" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "OriginalSubtotal" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "OriginalShippingCost" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "OrignalShippingTax" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "OriginalTax" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "OriginalDiscount" numeric(18,6) NOT NULL,
    "ReceivedDate" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "DispatchByDate" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "ProcessedDate" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "HoldOrCancel" bool NOT NULL,
    "CustomerHash" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "EmailHash" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "GetPostalCode" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    "TagId" uuid NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "IsRMA" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "ConversionType" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "ItemWeight" numeric(18,6) NULL,
    "TotalWeight" numeric(18,6) NULL,
    "PackageWeight" numeric(18,6) NULL,
    "PackageCount" int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT processedorder_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("OrderId"),
    CONSTRAINT processedorder_tagid_unique UNIQUE ("TagId")
)
WITH (
    fillfactor=50,
    autovacuum_enabled=false
);
CREATE INDEX ix_processedorder_receieveddate ON public.processedorder USING btree ("ReceivedDate" DESC NULLS LAST) WITH (fillfactor='50');
```

Here is a query:

```
SELECT SUM(o."ConvertedTotal") as "totalRevenue"
FROM public.processedorder o
WHERE o."ReceivedDate" BETWEEN '2020-07-23T00:00:00.000Z' and '2021-06-05T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Sometimes the query uses **ix_processedorder_receieveddate** index, sometimes not, I guess it depends on **startDate** and **endDate** params.

Here is a query plan of the query above:

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=92468.33..92468.34 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=371.130..371.131 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=92468.11..92468.32 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=371.074..371.105 rows=3 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=91468.11..91468.12 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=367.789..367.790 rows=1 loops=3)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on processedorder o  (cost=0.00..91121.46 rows=138661 width=7) (actual time=0.021..268.513 rows=114050 loops=3)
                    Filter: (("ReceivedDate" >= '2020-07-23 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("ReceivedDate" <= '2021-06-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 296245
```

Here is another the same query with different params:

```
SELECT SUM(o."ConvertedTotal") as "totalRevenue"
    FROM public.processedorder o
    WHERE o."ReceivedDate" BETWEEN '2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z' and '2021-06-05T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Here is the query plan of the last query:

```
Aggregate  (cost=42314.13..42314.14 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=89.767..89.768 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on processedorder o  (cost=500.94..42272.06 rows=16830 width=7) (actual time=9.696..66.717 rows=26347 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (("ReceivedDate" >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("ReceivedDate" <= '2021-06-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Heap Blocks: exact=2156
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_processedorder_receieveddate  (cost=0.00..496.73 rows=16830 width=0) (actual time=9.404..9.404 rows=26347 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (("ReceivedDate" >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("ReceivedDate" <= '2021-06-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
```

Basically the summation is over ~200,000 rows

Do you have any ideas guys, could it be because of invalid format of **timestamp** and it's not uses the index or what?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the **complete** execution plan, not just the part you think is important.

Comment: The first plan takes only 370**ms** and the second only 89**ms** - both times are far away from 30 _seconds_ (which would be 30000ms)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not including this part because for now it cached on production database and takes much less time.

Comment: Then please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: If it is faster "for now", then do you really have a problem?  When does it become slow again?  If it really is a problem, then when it does become slow again capture an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` with track_io_timing turned on, and post that.  The auto_explain extension might help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe stats are just out of date try `ANALYZE processedorder`

Also just for testing purposes you can force the use of the index by "disabling" sequential scans

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

### My guess

I would guess that it's PostgreSQL trying to optimize your results.
In this case I have no idea what to do about it.

You could try splitting the request in smaller chunks to verify this. If your time period is only a few days, does it use the index more reliably?

Take into account the number of rows filtered in your two examples. There is a huge difference. This might cause PostgreSQL to just go find the rows in the table without the index, as it's a large chunk of the entire tables content. Retrieving data from an index has it's own costs and the larger your chunk of data the greater this cost and the less your gain.

### What to do?

If this is an operation you repeat fairly often you might want to engineer another solution on how to request the data.

E.g. creating another table containing just the needed columns and maybe pre-aggregated day-wise, or whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for provided info.
I just wanted to be sure that I am not missing some simple stupid stuff here, if with this super simple query everything is fine as well as with index itself, then I need to think about something alternative.
Of course I can create trigger on the database side that would calculates SUM when new row adds or etc, but, yes, trying to find something stupid/simple/fast.

Comment: You're welcome! You might want to wait for some other suggestions, as this is just an educated guess. Also I don't know how to verify it which makes the info kind of worthless. I figured it might make sense if nothing else does, as it is a legitimate feature of the RDBMS.

Comment: You might also want to try out the solution offered by @eshirvana. This should (on default settings) remove the overhead of using the index; thus PostgreSQL should use it even for bigger time spans. That's most likely the simplest solution and might already be enough.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have an index on both "ConvertedTotal and "ReceivedDate" , that definitely improve your performance alot :

```
create index ix_name on processedorder (ReceivedDate,ConvertedTotal);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, man. I'll try it for sure.